# How to get P&L on a trade through Interactive Brokers TWS Java API

Tags: forex, tws, interactive-brokers

Is there any way to get Profit and Loss(daily & total till date) on a particular trade made on IB TWS through its Java API?

Comment: Do you have a connection from Java to TWS for free ?

Comment: @PantaRhei, I do have a paper trading account with IB and I am using the TWS Java API to make trades. I dont have any issue with making connection to TWS from Java API.

Comment: could you share the code where you connect to TWS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but not in the way you seem to be asking.  All profit and loss in the API is calculated by you until the trade is closed and then you can use the commissionReport method of the wrapper.  A commissionReport is sent after every execDetails.  [API doc](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/java/commissionreport_event.htm)

You can always check your statements for previous profits and losses.

The flow is like this.

- place trade and get fill price from execDetails
- get opening commission from commissionReport
- on every tick calculate open position profit, use bid/ask for realism, but it's all forex has anyway
- close trade and get price from execDetails
- get commission from commissionReport again
- calculate closed trade profit/loss
- also note that commissionReport has a field m_realizedPNL you can use, but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 2):

In the  TWS v9.72+ API there is a `reqPnl` method on the EClient which can be used to subscribe to real-time PnL (unrealized and realized) updates for a full portfolio via the associated method on the EWrapper

https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1EClient.html#a0351f22a77b5ba0c0243122baf72fa45

Additionally, for a single contractID, you can use: `reqPnLSingle` on the Client.

https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/interfaceIBApi_1_1EWrapper.html#aebeb008f2b763d7bed2969b66bbd1b33

Answer (score 0):

you may presubmit the order, to see all calculations, like the commission and margin impact of the order.

to do that, set whatIf=True in the order definition.

you'll then receive openOrder events, with all the calculations made for you.